# Making Tamales using a corn meal alternative

Tags: substitutions, corn, tamales

What can I use to make tamales other than corn meal? My son is allergic to corn.

Answer (score 5):

In some cuisines, the masa isn't usually corn at all. Sometimes it's rice, sometimes it's plantain and/or other starchy fruit. The tamale-like dish is actually called [pasteles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteles), but the difference between tamales and pasteles seems to be primarily the corn.

Check out this [informational link](http://www.puertoricanpasteles.com/) and these recipes from [Epicurious](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Puerto-Rican-Pasteles-em-Pasteles-Puertorriquenos-em-51203630) and [The Polynesian Kitchen](http://polynesiankitchen.blogspot.com/2009/08/pasteles-by-request.html); and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lu6br1YuIXg).

Making these wouldn't be like substituting a less than ideal ingredient for corn, because it isn't. Pasteles are a well loved dish in their own right. But once you know how to make the masa, you could certainly make a tamale recipe you like, but with the pasteles masa.